# "parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'" when using MutationObserver

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tampermonkey

I am a total noob at JS (as well as with the web development in general) :(

Currently, I am working on a small script for Tampermonkey, which looks after specific elements in a particular class and plays a sound whenever any changes occur with the element. (Value changes, elements hides/shows, etc.).

Currently, I have the following code:

```
     var audio = new Audio('URL_to_the_sound');
        var mutationObserver = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
      mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
        console.log(mutation);
          audio.play();
      });
    });
    var target = document.getElementsByClassName('CLASSNAME');
        mutationObserver.observe(target, {
      attributes: true,
      characterData: true,
      childList: true,
      subtree: true,
      attributeOldValue: true,
      characterDataOldValue: true
    });
```

However, my browser responds with the following error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'observe' on 'MutationObserver': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.`

I should mention that there are several elements in the same class.

What should I do? :(

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns a NodeList, not a single Node. You need to loop through it and create an observer for each element

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Can you provide me with the example of the code? I have tried adding a loop function; however, the web-page is not loading with it.

Comment: Might be easier to just use `waitForKeyElements`.

Comment: @wOxxOm Could you please provide a code example for the matter?

Comment: You can find a lot of those easily: [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=waitForKeyElements). The first result contains the script itself and the examples.

Comment: @wOxxOm OK, I figured it out. But, it fires only when the page is being loaded. It does not check for any changes after that. How can I get around that?

Comment: Those changes are not DOM mutations, I guess. You can inspect it in devtools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. I figured it out.
I have used the following function:

```
waitForKeyElements (
            "span.classname"
            , soundfx, false
        );
```

It works sort-of okay, I will play around with it to achieve better results.
Thanks to all who commented on this post! :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate over each element returned by **getElementsByClassName**. This method returns **HTMLCollection** which has no any loop-like method, but you could convert it to **Array**, and then use **forEach** method:

```
var targets = document.getElementsByClassName("CLASSNAME");

Array.from(targets).forEach(target => {
  mutationObserver.observe(target, {
    attributes: true,
    characterData: true,
    childList: true,
    subtree: true,
    attributeOldValue: true,
    characterDataOldValue: true
  });
});
```

Here is working example based on your code snippet:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-qbetr2

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work. :(
It stopped showing erroring messages, but it does not log any changes to the console and/or play a sound.

Comment: Which mutations do you want to observe on? I've edited my example on Stack Blitz. As you can see when I modified div's width attribute console log appeared.

Comment: I want to check whether the element is being toggled to be shown and check whether its value is being changed. (Ex. <span>'s with the class "test")

Comment: And how do you toggle visibility of element? I've provided a couple of example mutations in my example. There is also adding css class to element. All those mutation cause appearing console log.